# How many connections can a child process handle?

Tags: linux, apache, process, connection, listen

As per the official apache.org website:

The MaxConnectionsPerChild directive sets the limit on the number of connections that an individual child server process will handle before it dies.

I'd appreciate some clarifications:

Q1:Since this setting is within the context of prefork, does the number of connections mentioned above refer to connections requests(SYN_SENT) or accepted/established connections ? Under what situation, would it be good to expire it?

Q2: Unlike the parent that only handles listening on port 80, the preforked child handles both the listening and established connections. The limit of  concurrent incoming connection requests (SYN_SENT) it can handle at one time is restricted by the apache directive of MaxRequestWorkers while the ThreadsPerChild limits the number of concurrent ESTABLISHED sockets.  Is this correct ?

Q3: If children are listening on port 80, what would the parent be doing then?  Does it keep listening?

Thank you

Comment: I understand ThreadsPerChild is not used under the prefork mpm

Answer (score 0):

Depends on mpm used.
For a prefork mpm, a child process handles one connection (so serverlimit will equal MaxClients (Now called MaxRequestWorkers as of apache 2.4) .

Worker and event mpms use threads where one child can handle many connections.

Q1: No.
MaxConnectionsPerChild is now called MaxRequestsPerChild.
As per apache.org website,  MaxRequestsPerChild sets the total number of requests each child server process serves before the child dies.
The main reason for setting MaxRequestsPerChild is to avoid long-lived process induced memory leaks. 
The default MaxRequestsPerChild for the prefork MPM is 1000 and for the worker MPM is 0.

Q2: The concept itself is correct.
Though MaxRequestWorkers and ThreadsPerChild are not prefork mpm directives.

Q3: Parent keeps listening to prefork extra children as needed and delegates the listening to them so they serve incoming connection requests.

A good way to overcome the prefork 1 child/1 connection limitedness is to enable KeepAlive and its sub directives. This will allow clients/browsers to issue many simultaneous GET requests so they can fetch all page elements over 1 tcp connection. This reduces latency as it drastically cuts down on those expensive tcp handshakes. Most browsers nowadays support keep-Alive feature.

Make sure to impose a timeout with KeepAliveTimeout so those unclosed browser tabs don't hog your connections slots.